# Looping inside sqldf based on a vector

Tags: r, loops, seq, sqldf

I have a list of values that I have created with the seq function

```
x <- (seq(0,10080,by=50))
```

I want to add those values in my data frame in a new column called `sequence` where the value of `mycol` is between the i and the i+1 element in x

**first iteration**

```
test<-sqldf('select *, case when (mycol> first value of x  and mycol <= second value of x) then **second value** end as sequence from mydataframe')
```

**second iteration**

```
test<-sqldf('select *, case when (mycol> second value of x  and mycol <= third value of x) then **third value** end as sequence from test')
```

etc...till i pass on all the numbers in `x`

I do not understand how to create such a loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
for (i in seq(x)-1){
    qry <- paste0("select *, case when (mycol>", x[i], "  and mycol <= ", 
x[i+1], ") then ",  x[i+1], " end as sequence from mydataframe")
    test <- sqldf(qry)
}
```

Or using defined `f` function and `sapply`:

```
f <- function(a, b) { paste0("select *, case when (mycol>", a, "  and mycol <= ", b, ") then ",  b, " end as sequence from mydataframe") }
sapply(seq(x)-1, function(i) sqldf(f(x[i], x[i+1])))
```

Just adjust the right SQL query.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the advantage of SQL and use a correlated aggregate subquery in place of a loop. In this approach you use two dataframes, your original and the sequence.

If I understand your needs, essentially you need to find the highest value of `X` that the current row's `mycol` falls under, so use a `MIN()` correlated aggregate query.

```
seqdf <- data.frame(x=(seq(0,10080,by=50)))

test <- sqldf('SELECT d.*, d.MyCol, 
                    (SELECT Min(s.x) FROM seqdf s
                     WHERE s.x >= d.MyCol) As d.Sequence
              FROM mydataframe d')
```

Caveat: I am not too familiar with the `sqldf` package, so don't know if it supports such a subquery (though I believe it mirrors SQLite's dialect). But I do know SQL and this is compliant syntax.